# Django Postgresql jsonfield queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

```
p = Profile(name="Tanner", data={'daily__email': 'a@a.com', 'weekly__email': True})
p.save()
```

Profile model has jsonfield.

```
Profile.objects.filter(data__daily__email='a@a.com')
Profile.objects.filter(data__daily__email__startswith='a')
```

how can i find Tanner on queryset?..

how can i find Tanner on queryset?

Comment: Don't use a JSON blob if the data is structured.

Answer (score -1):

```py
Profile.objects.get(name="Tanner")
```

Get lookups error when it finds multiple entries with specified search criteria and will error when it does not find one matching entry.

```py
Profile.objects.filter(name="Tanner")
```

As your quesiton implies you are already familiar with filter lookups